# chrome.tabs.query(object) doesn't match definition

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I am trying to grab all tabs of the current window and loop through them.

currently using code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true}, function(result) {
    result.forEach(function(tab) {
        do stuff here;
    });
});
```

I have permissions for 'tabs' in the manifest.

It is throwing the error: "Error: Invocation of form tabs.query(object) doesn't match definition tabs.query(object queryInfo, function callback) at..."

I am confused as I clearly have the object and a callback function. I also see elsewhere that it can be done with a promise instead as:

```
var query = chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true});
query.then(function(tabs) {
    tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
        do stuff here;
    });
});
```

But this throws the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Promise-based approach is only valid in Firefox when using `browser.*` namespace instead of `chrome.*`

Chrome does not natively provide Promises for its API, though Mozilla [has a polyfill](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill) if you prefer that.

Your first snippet is correct and will not throw this error. Make sure you check all invocations of `tabs.query` **and properly reload the extension** for your changes to apply.

Comment: Thanks, it appears that it is working so not sure why I was getting the error.